# HTML hyperlink to cover several table cells

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple HTML table which has one row and two cells. The first cell has a hyperlink which should cover both cells. How could I get my hyperlink to cover the second td of my table?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px;padding:0">
      <a href="yes.htm" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;position:relative;top:0;left:0;right:0;display:block;margin:0;box-sizing:content-box;height:22px;line-height:22px;">Yes</a>
    </td>

    <td style="width:30px;padding:5px">Oh yeah</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now my hyperlink only covers the first td, but not the second one. What could be done?

I do not want to use JavaScript. I do not want to copy the link to both table cells.

Comment: Can you copy the a tag into the second td? Is javascript an option?

Comment: No, I cannot copy or use JavaScript here.

Answer (score 2):

as a link in each td is not a good alternative and using js is a bit dirty, here is another html/css approach:

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
<a class="table-row" href="/mylink">
    <div class="table-cell">...</div>
    <div class="table-cell">...</div>
    <div class="table-cell">...</div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.table { display:table; }
.table-row { display:table-row; }
.table-cell { display:table-cell; }
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2h5bhma/)

Personally, I would prefer to put a seperate link in each td that points to the same URL, to keep things simple:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://url/stuff">
                First column
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://url/stuff">
                Second column
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There is more CSS code for link hover, so the background colour will be changed on hover. In other words, separate links does not work as well as possible...

Comment: The second solution I have provided is just an example of what I would prefer to do. Please refer to the first solution for something which will enable you to have a single <a></a> tag around two <td></td> tags. Essentially what is happening here is that I am styling these <div></div> tags as table elements so that they can be wrapped in a single <a></a> tag

Answer (score 1):

```
    <table style="position: relative">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px;padding:0">
      <a href="yes.htm" style="position: absolute; width: 100%">Yes</a>
    </td>

    <td style="width:30px;padding:5px">Oh yeah</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

By making the link absolute you pull it out of it's layer and by giving it a width of 100, the link extends to the next TD element.

To prevent the anchor tag from overflowing, give the table a relative position to confine the absolute element to the table width.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2h5bhma/71/)